# Move 'current-menu-item' class on #adminmenu li from Posts to Pages for Taxonomy Edit Screen

Tags: functions, custom-taxonomy, wp-admin, admin, admin-menu

I've created a custom taxonomy called 'venuecategory' that is hidden by design(not attached to a CPT and does not appear in admin menu).  When I'm on this taxonomy's admin page ('wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=venuecategory') the admin menu highlights Posts like this:

[image: Venue Categories Posts Screenshot]

My goal is to make Pages highlighted and open instead, like this:

[image: Venue Categories Pages Screenshot]

Seems kinda odd, I know, but my reason is that I'm creating a filterable gallery on a page called Venues which is using this Venue Categories taxonomy to categorize the rows of an ACF repeater.  I've added a meta box on the Venues page with a button that links out to this taxonomy admin page.

Normally, I would do this via Custom Post Type, but in this case it's overkill.